# Calendar api for android 2.3

Tags: android

I want to show the users calendar in my android app and  also add , delete or modify the events for particular  date. I searched for this and i got answers for android 4 . so if anybody having tutorial about this(android 2.3)? or any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Android API level 10 and below do not provide any library to interface application with the native calendar. CalendarView API is only available for OS v3.0 and above. So, It'd be better to either design a custom calendar, or use the native one for devices with OS above 3.0

Comment: Have worked out it in 2.3.3 .i'm getting the following errors  1) Failed to find provider info for calendar 2)Failed to find provider info for com.android.calendar while running on emulator. how to solve these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official API for using Calendar on Android versions before version 4.0. 
You can use provider with following

```
content://com.android.calendar/calendars
```

but there's no guarantee it will work on all devices. This calendar is synchronising with  Google. You can find more details on [this link](http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-provider-tests/source/browse/trunk/src/com/androidbook/androidcalendar/CalendarActivity.java) and also on [this one](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar-3850276.htm)